# How long should wubi take to install Lubuntu ?

Tags: installation, wubi, lubuntu, bittorrent

I tried installing Ubuntu with `wubi` but it took too long on one file.

I'm installing it with 18GB on a 64GB flash drive. It was an amd64.iso. torrent thing.

So I tried installing lubuntu instead and everything else took shorter to install but its stuck on the `.iso` torrent again.

How long should it take and am i doing something wrong ?

[image: It always gets stuck at this point in the installation. Sometimes I leave it for a really long time. The remaining time goes up and down so I know it isn't frozen.]

I am using Windows 7 and letting wubi do it for me. I'm not so good with computers.

Comment: First, how are you downloading your Ubuntu image? Are you letting WUBI do it or doing it yourself? What version of Ubuntu are you using? Wind Windows version? Do you have a screenshot?

Comment: If you want to install Ubuntu to a flash drive, download this software: [link](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/#button)

Comment: Pleas register, and contact StackExchange to merge your users, you have more than one user, and that is putting all your edits through review: http://askubuntu.com/contact

Answer (score 0):

You should have atleast a speed of 200kbps of internet speed this will install ubuntu fast but if you have less than 50kbps of internet speed than it take more than 6hrs or it will not install